# Android: Detect long press on the whole activity

Tags: java, android

How can i detect a long press on the whole activity? since onLongClickListener is only for individual views.I want to run a method everytime the user longpress the screen

Comment: Add listener for parent layout..

Comment: I tried that but It didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override your activity's `dispatchTouchEvent()` method.  You also need a gesture detector in order to determine which motion events are 'long presses'. Put this into your activity:

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // The code for when a long-press happens
    }
});

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Please note that I did not test the above code.

Answer (score 0):

A long press is actually multiple registers of the key. So you could do a `while` loop on the input and as long as input is not `NULL` run the method you want. If I understood you correctly this should do the trick...